# Setting Billable Limits

Tags: google-api

From the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/): When trying to change the Billable Limits for the project under the Quota page, I keep getting the error: **Your input was invalid**. 
The error message is not very informative, doesn't specify which input was invalid or why it was invalid.

I've experimented with this in IE, Firefox, and Chrome. I've also turned off all other APIs except for Custom Search API (which I'd like to increase the limit for) without any luck.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? how can it be solved?

Comment: This is happening to me too.  I wonder if its because the quota page is using the old console, and they're trying to move to the new one.

Comment: Ethan, I thought the same as well. I was hoping that there might be a simpler solution or that the Google API team might see this post. It is odd that a product which we pay for has a bug such as this one. I would think this would be a priority to fix.

Comment: I was able to get in contact with Google Enterprise Support, and the person I talked to agreed with me that this is a bug.  He's passed the issue on to their engineering team.  So we'll see what happens...

Comment: Hi Ethan, do you have any updates on this issue or a ticket number to track with Google?

Comment: I haven't heard anything for a while.  I might bug them again.

Comment: Just got a reply back that it should be fixed.  Tried to update billable limits and it worked!  Maybe give it a try now.

Comment: Hi Ethan, how did you contact Google about this? I am having the same problem too.

Answer (score 0):

(response from a Google employee)
This can happen if a "restricted" API is enabled on the project. "Restricted" APIs can only be seen by specifically enabled users. For instance, the Google Maps Javascript API v2 has been marked "restricted" because it was retired in 2013, and no user should see this API anymore (and instead, use v3).

Work is underway to remove the Google Maps Javascript API v2 from all the existing projects. A systemic fix is being worked on (internal Google reference #12001333), but in the meantime, if you see this error, the best workaround is to use a different API project.

Comment: Not a very good solution we cannot switch everything to different project right now. Anything else, maybe?